# p:dataExporter in HTML Format is not working

Tags: primefaces, data-export

As Per My Requirement HTML DataExporter need in primefaces Datatable. Is There any Possible way data exporting in html format. Please Suggest Any solution.

```
<h:commandLink>
                                        <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/pdf.png" />
                                        <p:dataExporter type="html" target="tbl" fileName="aaaaa" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
```

Comment: What does the documentation and showcase tell you?

Comment: I need Export the data in datatable using  primefaces.

Comment: That is not what the showcase and documentation contain, that is your requirement, and the was/is clear. Let me rephrase. Is there any indication in the showcase or documentation that exporting to html is supported?

Comment: In Documentaion not mentioned but i tried Using like exporting data in pdf ,csv and etc...This code is not working that's why i posted this question..

Comment: So if the documentation does not mention it, it is just not supported. Solutions: Enhance the dataexporter or write your own.

Comment: Thanks for editing the title... But it still is not supported... ;-). The answer is valid, so either please accept it or remove the question if you think it indeed was just an 'rtfm'...

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because it is **not supported**. The first line in the PrimeFaces 5.3 [documentation of the dataExporter](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#133) states:

> DataExporter is handy for exporting data listed using a Primefaces
>   Datatable to various formats  such as excel, pdf, csv and xml.

and a little below at the definition of the type attribute:

> type   null    String     Export type: "xls","pdf","csv", "xml"

Solutions:

- Take the source and add 'html' as a supported type
- Write your own new dataExporter